# Review Limit reached without actually reviewing anything

Tags: support, review

Based on my reputation (between 500 and 750), I should be able to cast Close and Reopen votes as well as access the First Posts and Late Answers review queues.

When I try to access both of those review queues, it tells me "*Daily up/down vote limit reached; come back in 8 hours.*" But, if I look under the stats, I see that I have done 0 reviews today.

How can I have reached my daily review limit in the queue when I haven't actually reviewed anything?

Answer (score 2):

That means you have done your maximum daily votes on questions/answers (40). I suppose the assumption is that you should be able to vote on questions/answers to access those review queues.

~8 hours in when the "day" switches for StackExchange